# How can I build Git 2.4.5 for Windows 7 x64?

Tags: git, visual-studio, nmake

How can I build Git 2.4.5 for Windows 7 x64? I downloaded zip-file of code sources and extracted it. If I try to build these sources through `nmake` utility of MS Visual Studio 2013, then I get an error:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you actually want to *build* Git, or simply to have a newer version than the official 1.9.5 that's currently available via git-scm.com?

The [`git-for-windows`](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) project will be replacing msysgit as the official Windows build of Git later this year. It has been making prereleases available on [its GitHub releases page](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) for some time, the latest of which at the time of writing is a preview based on Git 2.4.5.

If you truly want to build it yourself, I strongly recommend using the sources from this project since it will eventually be the source of stable releases and it contains "Windows-specific patches". [Its "Building Git" wiki page](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Building-Git) is probably your best guide.

Comment: Thank you for answer and useful links, @Chris! I am reading the book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 . It recomends to use git 2.0 or newer. But official version for windows here https://git-scm.com/download/win is 1.9.5. Therefore I tried to build the latest version myself. I didn't know what the http://git-for-windows.github.io/ is exists. Building Git  is interesting to me also, therefore your link to wiki page is useful for me too. Thank you again!